# C# запись в ACC, минуя Wav

Tags: c#, аудио, naudio

Нужно каким то образом записать звук с микрофона, и сохранить это в формате ACC. Есть NAudio, но там сначала пишется в Wav, и только потом можно конвертнуть. Есть у кого какие-нибудь предложения?

Comment: Ну так берите сэмплы, а там кодируйте как вам надо, кодек raw.

Comment: Найдите как получить стрим (System.IO.Stream) с микрофона, найдите семпл, соидените их вместе.